# How to solve error during intialization of VM for Java due to UFT/QTP?

Tags: java, uft14

I used to have UFT for Test Automation. Now I don't require it so, I have uninstalled it.
Tried to install AdoptOpenJDK 11(LTS) for x64 based system. When I try to locate it using java -version, I get the following error.
[image]

The path of Javabin directory of AdoptOpenJDK is added in environment variable %PATH% and %JAVA_HOME%
[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Some feedback on your first question: Instead of using images, put the actual text into your question, this makes it easier to come up in search and easier to read. What instructions did you follow to install AdoptOpenJDK? What OS are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am using windows 10 (x64) and used msi from adoptopenjdk. Solved the issue, path variable had entry of uft, removed it and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

UFT uses a few windows environment variables locations for java.

Check out what you have in these:

```
%_JAVA_OPTIONS%
%IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS%
%JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS%
```

If they contain a reference to the UFT bin directory (and you've uninstalled UFT) then remove the reference.